# best way to convert linq to sql to linq entites

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have an asp.net web forms application that uses linq 2 sql.  A lot of the controls are databound to linq datasource controls.

I want to clean up this application so I can easily use html5's offline functionality.

I thought I should probably move my linq 2 sql statements from code behind to classes and then call to the class.  Not sure?

What I would like to do, is have a clean separation and since MS is no longer promoting linq 2 sql, I would like to move to linq 2 entities.

Eventually, a while from now, I would like to convert this app into mvc, but one step at a time.

Would it be better to just make separate data classes for each form or just create database first linq to entity classes?

Thanks,

Sheri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend reviewing the Repository Pattern suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175/repository-pattern-tutorial-in-c-sharp). I've been using the Repository Pattern with LINQ-to-SQL and ASP.NET MVC since 2009, and it has been very good for me for managing my data interactions, maintaining separation of concerns, and, especially, testing.

Comment: That is interesting and I will look further into it. Does it work well with web forms and is Microsoft planning on supporting it in the future?

Comment: I'm using it combined with ASP.NET Web API in a WebForms project I inherited in my new position. The current project is a typical WebForms implementation...presentation, business logic and data access all jumbled into the code behinds. I'm in the process of extracting the data access layer into its own HTTP service, which is why I'm using Web API. It's all the middleware goodness of ASP.NET MVC packaged up with the disconnection and decoupling of Web Services.